# Unable to run a arangoDB foxx app successfully

Tags: arangodb

I am new to arangoDB. It's exciting that you may create APIs on top of ArangoDB with help of foxx framework. Somehow I am failing to run/create a foxx app successfully. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here. Following is details of configuration and steps I am following to run foxx hello app. As guided in https://github.com/arangodb/foxx-apps .

- ArangoDB 1.4.3 (64x)
- Windows 7 Pro (64x)
- Install location (C:\triAGENS), added to system path

**Commands running from user directory.**

Command: `arangod.bat`
[image: Command: arangod.bat]
Command: `foxx-manager.bat update` and `foxx-manager.bat install hello-foxx /hello`
[image: <code>foxx-manager.bat update</code> and <code>foxx-manager.bat install hello-foxx /hello</code>]

**Commands running from installation directory.**

Command: `arangod.bat`
[image: Command: arangod.bat]
Command: `foxx-manager.bat update` and `foxx-manager.bat install hello-foxx /hello`
[image: <code>foxx-manager.bat update</code> and <code>foxx-manager.bat install hello-foxx /hello</code>]

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer to part 1)

Unfortunately there is a bug in the installer script for windows, this will be fixed in the next release.
As a quick fix for you:
You can edit the .bat files (arangod.bat, arangosh.bat, foxx-manager.bat etc.) in these files there are references to some files/folders like ".\data" or "arangod.conf“ if you add absolute paths to these files/folders it will be working from any location on your filesystem.

Answer to part 2)

this behavior is due to a bug in ArangoDBs communication with github.
ArangoDB internally requires a content-length to be set when downloading a file.
Github however does cache this size only for a limited period of time after each download, after this period the content-length is dropped and recalculated during the next download (so the next download does not send a content-length).

This causes your error message from time to time.

To fix it:
Just run the same command again (retrigger the download)

The core team has this bug on the radar and will fix it in one of the upcoming versions.

Comment: Thanks @mchacki , Your answer to 2nd part works but some how I am still unable to run it from any directory (even after changing .\data and conf files to absolute path). I suppose I need to take a clue from your suggestions and try to fiddle with locations of more resources. Even if not it's enough for me to experiment with ArangoDB and I can wait for future releases.

Answer (score 4):

a small update on this:

**part 1**:

In most recent versions of ArangoDB (1.4.8+), you can use the web interface to upload a Foxx application from a zip file. So you don't need to use the command-line tools.
For example, you could download the "hello-foxx" app as a zip file from Github (https://github.com/arangodb/hello-foxx/archive/master.zip) and use the web interface to upload the zip to your server.

**part 2**:
The annoying "internal error" issue has been fixed in recent 1.4 versions though there may still be some temp file directory issue as pointed out here:
https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues/743